# Imposing context bound on parameter of parameter

Tags: scala

In the following example I try to impose a context bound on the Point argument of Link to be viewable as a RadPoint.

```
trait Link[Point, +A <: Link[Point, A]] {
}

type ViewableAsRadPoint[T] = T => RadPoint

def compute[Point: ViewableAsRadPoint, Link <: Link[Point, Link]](link: Link)
```

Can I get rid of the exposing Point in compute? Something like:

```
def compute[Link <: Link[_ : ViewableAsRadPoint, Link]](link: Link)
```

Thanks!

dero

Answer (score 1):

You can make `Point` type parameter visible from outside as a member type:

```
trait Link[Point, +A <: Link[Point, A]] {
  type Pt = Point
}
```

And then extract the context bound `_ : ViewableAsRadPoint` as an equivalent implicit parameter of that member type:

```
def compute[L <: Link[_, L]](link: L)(
  implicit view: ViewableAsRadPoint[link.Pt]) = ???
```